# Tee and Grep, filtering and appending the output of a script several times

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tee

I have a script that output logs every 30 minutes, this logs are appended to a file that store all logs, then I filter the logs that contains 'Maas" string and store those logs to another file.

```
(script output) | tee -a alldata.log | grep 'Maas' >> filterMaas.log
```

What I need to do is to add more filters to output to several files, the following line doesnt work, the file filterCCSA.log is empty.

```
(script output) | tee -a alldata.log | grep 'Maas' >> filterMaas.log | grep 'CCSA' >> filterCCSA.log
```

Any idea how can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```sh
(script output) | tee >(grep 'Maas' >> filterMaas.log) >(grep 'CCSA' >> filterCCSA.log)  >> alldata.log
```